# How to model rocks and stones as in the image?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, displacement, polycount

I want to model a image of rock below-

[image: Rock]

But, I'm not getting sharp edge image of Rock, when I use Displacement map generated by Njob to displace poly

This is what I'm getting -

[image: Smooth image]

And as we can see the model is too smooth to be used, also it is not looking as a model of rock

Also, the displacement map I've got is -

[image: displacement map]

**So, I want to ask what is the best way to model the rocks as shown in the reference image?**

Thanks in Advance,

**Also, I don't want too high poly rock, because that is to be used in a game.**

PS - 
1. Rendered in Blender Internal
2. Want the quickest way

Comment: Don't make it more complicated, if it's for a game, make the rock by hand and apply texture to it. The displacement map is not going to work as expected if the object doesn't ahve high enough polys

Comment: How to make it by hand? @tacofisher

Comment: Good looking rocks are though... related:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93981/workflow-for-modeling-assets-like-this-picture-included